# Changing Axes Values in MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a matrix of values (potentially quite big), which I have decoded into values of -1, 0 and 1 based on some rules. I want to use the `MatrixPlot` to see the pattern.

My issue is that the `MatrixPlot` automatically assigns the integer values corresponding to the position in the matrix in my case. However, instead of the (integer) positions, I want to use my own grid (xrow and ycolumn) of the same size on the axes. I have tried to use `FrameTicks`, but clearly it is a wrong command as it pushed my x and y values to the corner.

```
rules = {-1 -> Red, 0 -> White, 1 -> Green}; 
RegWhich = {{-1, 0, 1,1},{0, 0, 0,-1}, {0,0,1,1}};
xrow = Range[0.1, 0.12, 0.01]; 
ycolumn = Range[0.01, 0.04, 0.01];
MatrixPlot[RegWhich, ColorRules -> rules, Frame -> True, Mesh -> True,
      MeshStyle -> Black, 
     PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[rules[[All, 2]], rules[[All, 1]]]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `FrameTicks`:

```
yticks = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, xrow];
xticks = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &,  ycolumn];
MatrixPlot[RegWhich, ColorRules -> rules, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks}, {xticks, xticks}}, Mesh -> True, 
 MeshStyle -> Black, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[rules[[All, 2]], rules[[All, 1]]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** If you want the first row at the bottom of the plot add the option `DataReversed -> True` to get

[image]

Alternatively, you can `Reverse` the input matrix rows and use `DataRange`:

```
MatrixPlot[Reverse@RegWhich, ColorRules -> rules, 
 DataRange -> {{.01, .04}, {.1, .12}},
 FrameTicks -> {{xrow, xrow}, {ycolumn, ycolumn}}, Mesh -> True, 
 MeshStyle -> Black, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[rules[[All, 2]], rules[[All, 1]]]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another quick question, how can I have the reverse order of the rows (as in, with 0.1 on the bottom corner)?

Comment: @NataliaK, please see the update.